# Why this Factorial function returning zero for large numbers

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating factorial of large numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384160/calculating-factorial-of-large-numbers-in-c)

Firstly, I am new to C++. I have tried below program to calculate factorial of any number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned long factorial(unsigned long n){
   return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1);
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter any Number to calculate factorial." <<endl;
  unsigned long n;
  cin >> n ;
  cout << factorial(n)    ;
}
```

If i give small numbers like 5,3,20 it returns me exact value. But if I give numbers like 34 etc.. It is returning me zero. I assume that it is exceeding the limit range. Please help me on this to return exact result whatever the number I enter.

Comment: If you always want exact numbers, you'll need to use a bignum library

Comment: If you just want a simple function to help you play with C++, try the Fibonacci sequence instead. Factorial grows way too fast to be much fun.

Answer (score 7):

Factorials are **huge**.

```
34! = 295232799039604140847618609643520000000
```

This barely fits into 128 bits. If your compiler supports a 128-bit number type, you can use it to calculate factorials up to 34. If not, or if you need anything larger, you will need to use some kind of [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) library.