# Why does this factorial function break after a certain point?

Tags: c

So I have this factorial function written in C:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n){
        int fn = 1;

        if(n == 0 || n == 1){
                return 1;
        } else{
                for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
                        fn *= i;
                }
        }

        return fn;
}
```

I tested it out with smaller numbers like 5 and it worked. Then I put it into this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                printf("\n%d! = %d", i, factorial(i));
        }
```

When `i` reaches 17, the factorial is apparently -288522240 which is obviously wrong. These kinds of answers continue until `i` reaches 34 and it says that the factorial is 0. It then does this for the rest of the numbers.

I don't understand what's wrong with my code. I see no reason for the number to become negative or 0. What's happened here?

Comment: Every numerical type in C has a certain range of values it can contain.

Comment: `unsigned int` is most likely a 32-bit integer. Those factorials get really big really quickly.

Comment: Integer overflow

Comment: Try this: `printf("\n%u! = %u", i, factorial(i));` ;)

Comment: Factorial of 100 is a 185-digit number. I doubt your ints are that big.

Comment: If you're doing this as a homework assignment, learning about the limits of integer types is probably one of the goals.

Comment: Factorials up to 12! fit into a 32-bit integer.  Factorials up to 20! fit into a 64-bit integer. After that, you've run out of bits on most machines.  However, 34! fits into an unsigned 128-bit integer, 57! fits into a 256-bit integer, and 98! fits into an unsigned 512-bit integer.

Answer (score 4):

100! or  9.3326...E+157 or 
9332621544394415268169923885626670049071596826438162146859296389521759999322991560894146397615651828625369792082722375825118521091686400000000000000000000000, a 525 bit number, is outside the range of `int` - likely 32-bit [-2147483648 ... 2147483647]

Signed integer math that overflows is *undefined behavior* (UB).  In OP's case, it appears that the lower 32-bits of the product `fn * i`, as 2's complement, was the result.  Eventually enough multiplication of even numbers kept shifting the non-zero portion of the product "to the  left" and resulted in that lower 32 bits becoming 0.

To calculate large factorials one needs another approach.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47514950/2410359)